# Is it possible to stream data using websockets

Tags: javascript, extjs, websocket

I have large dataset to send to client side instead of waiting for full transfer data ..

I'm interested to know if there is any way stream of data can be enabled which keeps on pushing the data to client side table and in meanwhile user can view the data.

Using Ext JS and WebSockets, Tried buffered grid performance is not good.

Comment: You probably don't even need websockets for this. Load the paginated data in chunks using regular AJAX calls and add it to a regular table row-by-row if you want to end up with the whole data set in the resulting document.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks for suggestion. Yes the conventional approach we had implemented chunking logic at server side which sends the set 200 records till all records are sent. I'm interested to explore if something out of box feature availalbe in websockets to achieve this without custom implementation at server side.

Comment: WebSockets is the opposite of "out-of-the-box" really - it's a more low-level API than AJAX calls. It's intended for when you need lower latency and "real-time" behaviour, like in a chat app.

Comment: yes .. i'm trying to use this for real time stock ticker list .. the moment user search for new criteria .. grid start showing results immediately and behind the scene keep getting rest of data via chunking mechanism.

Comment: So, new rows would be added to the grid as the stocker emits updates? Or do you just need it to display a single, very large snapshot of data?

Comment: it will be updated whenever there is update on user existing search results + snapshot data could be large as user might request data for multiple stocks in one go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18994/discussion-between-nas-and-millimoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebSocket protocol defines its own framing. The client will process one frame at a time. For you this means that you need to break your data into chunks and send many of them over the wire.

That will allow the client to process them as they come in as opposed to buffering 40000 records in memory until all of them have arrived.